# Result Sum in excel is = -

Tags: excel, ms-office

[image]I try to sum from some sum in cell, but the result become "-"

`=SUM(X136;X124;X188;X111)` 
`= -`

What must i do to fix this?

Comment: Show data what is in that cells. Without that is hard to tell anything.

Comment: Data just like this (1 ; 123 ; no resutl from sum; 111)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, please provide example, screenshot or something that shows your problem.

Comment: @Magiczne like a pict on the top

Comment: I still don't know what's in other cells you reference in the formula. I would look for the first cell where the "-" character appears and look for problem there. If you still don't know try to make simple spreadsheet and then show it with all of the cells visible on screenshot

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please see [ask] for tips on how to ask good questions.

Comment: You try to ommit one by one of the elements to check which one the trouble

Comment: I'M still don't  know, can you tell me specific @user11982798

Comment: Test sum(X136;X136), then sum(X136;X124), then sum(X136;X124;X188),  and then sum(X136;X124;X188;X111), which one is not correct?

Comment: If your Cell elements are formula, you try to modify your elements add if is not number give 0

Comment: I suspect the sum simply is 0. Please check the cell's number format. If it is accounting format without currency symbol, then `-` is shown if value is `0`.

Comment: Still not work, the results still "-" @user11982798

Comment: Ya, the format  is accounting without  currency  @AxelRichter

Comment: Which one give - from those four test of sum? The first, second, third or fourth?

Comment: Ya I try, but doesn't work... I'm Confused.  That is setting from format or etc @user11982798

Comment: And check your regional settings, usually use sum(a,b,c) not sum(a;b;c)

Comment: That (a;b;c) @user11982798

Comment: What the result if your formula is = sum(X136;X136) and if is = sum (X136,X136)

Comment: If I use (x136,x126) , error...@user11982798

Comment: The last, format your Cell

Answer (score 0):

A dash (minus sign) isn't the result of a calculation. Therefore it's a substitute put there by a cell format.

1. Right-click the cell where the dash appears, select *Format cells* from the context menu, look at the *Number* tab. I believe you will see a *Custom* format. It might be as simple as "-", meaning that any result of the calculation is shown as a dash or it might be a formula like [>0]"-",0,0 with similar effect. Take note of it and set the format to "General"
2. Copy or write your formula to a cell the format of which you know not to be *Custom*, in fact, one where the format is "General". Since we don't know how the cell formats were set in your worksheet the only way to be sure may be to format a cell as "General" yourself. To copy the formula without the cell format from where you take the copy you must select the cell and copy the formula from the **Formula bar** (above the grid - don't copy from the cell). Then select the cell you prepared with the "General" format and paste the formula to the **Formula bar** (not directly to the cell). The result should be a proper calculation.